# Angular2 routed component interaction with parent

Tags: angular, components, interaction, injectable

Please consider the bellow diagram for my application

[image]

EventsHub is a simple injectable service :

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject}    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class EventsHub {
    private announcementSource = new Subject<string>();
    messageAnnounced$ = this.announcementSource.asObservable();

    announce( message : string)  {
        console.log('eventHub : firing...'+message);
        this.announcementSource.next(message);
   }
}
```

The problem is when 'announce' function is called from within Funds,Clients or any other component inside the router-outlet , the parent (MainApp) will not receive any messages.

On the other hand,when I call the same service function from  NavigationMenu , MainApp receives the event just fine.
So how is it supposed for routed components to interact with their parent ?

Thanks

this case has been tested on RC1 & RC2

Comment: It can interact with `EventEmitters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you provide `EventsHub` only once on a common parent (root component). DI maintains a single instance for every provider. If you provide it at every component that uses it every component gets a different instance. So one component listens on one instance and the other emits on another one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was injecting EventsHub in the child component 'Providers'. Once removed it from there , problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

For example your `Funds` component could have an EventEmitter

```
@Output() someEvent: EventEmitter<SomeResult> = new EventEmitter<SomeResult>();
```

Then your Funds could emit this event my calling:

```
this.someEvent.emit({'Hello', 'from', 'the', 'other','side'});
```

Comment: AFAIK It is not allowed to use EventEmitter within Service. Yet I tried it and it didn't work.

Comment: @Output is not supported inside routed components.

Comment: So is the `Funds` a service then?

Comment: Funds is a component , communicates with its parent using the EventsHub service.